# HTML select with transparent text after selection?

Tags: jquery, html, colors, html-select

I have a HTML select with different colored background options. It works fine but I need to one little thing. The text in the dropdown options should only appear when the dropdown is open. Basically when I select an option I want transparent text so I can only see colors.

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('select[id^=dropdown]').children().each(function () {
            colors = { "N": "lightgrey", "G": "green", "O": "orange", "A": "yellow", "R": "red", "U": "purple" }
            $(this).attr('style', 'background-color:' + colors[$(this).val()] + ';');
        });
        $('select[id^=dropdown]').change(function () {
            $(this).attr('style', $(this).find('option:selected').attr('style'));
        }).change();
    });
```

HTML select:

```
<select class="selectElement" runat="server" id="dropdown_test">
    <option value="N">N</option>
    <option value="G">G</option>
    <option value="O">O</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="R">R</option>
    <option value="U">U</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, works in every browser including IE:

html

```
    <select id="select1" onchange="colourFunction()">
<option class="white" value="A">This should have a WHITE background</option>
<option class="red" value="B">This should have a RED background</option>
<option class="yellow" value="C">This should have a YELLOW background</option>
<option class="green" value="D">This should have a GREEN background</option>
</select>
```

css

```
#select1 {width:150px; color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);}
#select1:focus, #select1:focus {
color:black;
}
.white {background:white;}
.red {background:red;}
.yellow {background:yellow;}
.green {background:green}
```

js

```
function colourFunction() {
var myselect = document.getElementById("select1"),
colour = myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].className;
myselect.className = colour;
myselect.blur(); //This just unselects the select list without having to click
somewhere else on the page
}
```

HTH :)

Answer (score 1):

If you still want the transparent text option, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dropdown').children().each(function () {
        colors = { "N": "lightgrey", "G": "green", "O": "orange", "A": "yellow", "R": "red", "U": "purple" }
        $(this).attr('style', 'background-color:' + colors[$(this).val()] + ';');
        $('#dropdown option').css('color','black'); 
    });

    $('#dropdown').change(function() { SetStyle(this) })


});

SetStyle('#dropdown'); //Set the style immediately

function SetStyle(obj) { 
    var color = $(obj).find('option:selected').css('background-color');
    $(obj).css({
        'color':'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        'background-color':color
    });
}
```

So here we go, final attempt! This will set the background color on load and will set the color to transparent. Then it will set the color of all options to black. So it will appear like there is no text on the dropdown but then there is when it's open. But in reality, there is text and it is black, you just can't see it whilst it's closed.

This is better than my previous answer :)

Notice I have amended your selector from

```
 $('select[id^=dropdown]')
```

to

```
 $('#dropdown')
```

You don't need to select elements where attribute 'Id' is equal to xxx, '#' is short for that :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I also realised that the text goes away after selections. When I add your code to my current jquery code it makes the text transparent all the time. What I am looking for is the text should only appear when the dropdown is open.

Comment: It's my mistake I didn't clearly state exactly what I wanted. I really appreciate your help though :)

Comment: Hey dude, great solution. I want the text to only appear in options. Your code works best so far but I can still see option "N" on page load.

Comment: I managed to fix that now by adding 'color: trasparent' to my select class. However, this does not work for IE(hate it). Anyways thank you so much for your help and time :)

Comment: You're welcome. Final attempt now up there, I think that will work better for you. I'm off home now.

Comment: You have helped me a lot! I tried the latest code but the #dropdown stops the code from working on the select dropdowns. The previous code worked exactly the way I want so I am happy with that. The only problem was I could not get the text to be transparent on Internet Explorer.

Comment: Basically I am building an ASP.NET web form application using ASP controls and HTML elements which sumbit data into SQL Server database. The select dropdowns are required to be color coded with black text when dropdown is open but transparent text when dropdown is closed (by default). I have achieved this in every browser except IE. I cannot thank you enough for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Use this :**
For remove text when you select item

```
$('select[id^=dropdown]').change(function () {
    var elem = $(this).children("*[value='" + $(this).val() + "']");
    elem.data("backup",elem.html()).html("");
    $(this).attr('style', 'background-color:' + colors[elem.val()] + ';');
});
```

But you need t declare array color out.